# display value of custom field in woocommerce content-product.php

Tags: woocommerce, custom-fields

I want to display the value of a custom-field in the content-product.php in woocommerce. I did like this, but the output is only the word "array".

where is my mistake? 
Thanks a lot!
rabox

```
    <?php if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;

// Ensure visibility
if ( empty( $product ) || ! $product->is_visible() ) {
return;
}
?>
<li <?php post_class(); ?>>



<span class="product_additional_info"><?php echo get_post_meta($post-
>ID, ‚additional-info‘, true); ?></span>
```

Comment: There are typos in '<?php echo get_post_meta($post-
>ID, ‚additional-info‘, true); ?>' e.g, ", ,'  should be ", '"

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the answer due to my bad english. ;) You mean the ‚additional-info‘ which should be rather  'additional-info‘ ? I tried different ways. That was only the last code I used. But none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found a piece of code that works here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179451/unable-to-display-custom-fields-on-woocommerce-product-pages

It goes like that:

```
    <?php

    $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $my_custom_field = $custom_fields["Name of your Field"];
    foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value ) {
    echo "<strong>$key: </strong> $value <br />";
    }

    ?>
```

Would be interesting to know why I cannot use the "wordpress-way" of using custom fields.

Comment: What do you mean by the "wordpress-way"? If you mean the same as your earlier question, I think that way should have worked. I don't think the code you actually posted (which could not actually run because of a typo)  matches the exact result you claimed. If you show me exactly the code you are running with the exact matching result I believe I can get it to work. So, if you are really interested re-edit that post and I will help you.

Comment: That is the "wordpress-way": 

    <?php get_post_meta($post_id, '$key', $single); ?>

And that does not work for some reason that I do not understand. 
But the code I found and posted works. You just have to adapt "Name of Your Field".

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce `content-product.php` uses `global $product;` so you can get the product id with `$product->get_id()`

Now, you can get the value of custom field by passing the product id and custom field name in `get_post_meta();`

**Example:** `get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_your_custom_field', true );`